# ¿Como cambiar color de fondo solo a ciertos elementos de un grid?

Tags: css, html5, css3, wordpress, wordpress-theme

¡Saludos! Necesito una ayudita con un tema de CSS, la cosa es que estoy desarrollando un proyecto con Wordpress y utilizo un plugin para mostrar los post en un grid.El tema es que he colocado para que se muestren 3 columnas, cada foto tiene un botón de "Read more", sin embargo, en cada columna los botones deben tener colores diferentes, he investigado un poco y he intentado con pares e impares pero no me funciona o no sé que estoy haciendo mal. Dejo el código de la grid a continuacion:

```html
<div id="post-grid-178" class="post-grid grid">
<div class="grid-nav-top"></div>
<div class="grid-items " id="">
<div class="item mix skin even flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media">
<a href="/../2018/10/23/a-canary-tells-its-owner-when-they-have-visitors/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/sharon-mccutcheon-617866-unsplash-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">A canary tells its owner when they have visitors</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/a-canary-tells-its-owner-when-they-have-visitors/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/get-to-know-the-dog-army-in-india/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/animal-animal-photography-blur-89781-300x208.jpg"></a></div>


<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">Get to know the dog army in India</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/get-to-know-the-dog-army-in-india/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/the-5-fastest-races-in-the-world/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Galgo_español-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">The 5 fastest races in the world</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/the-5-fastest-races-in-the-world/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/what-should-you-know-before-you-have-a-cat/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/eric-han-540884-unsplash-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">What should you know before you have a cat?</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/what-should-you-know-before-you-have-a-cat/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/adorable-animal-blur-825949-1.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">Why pitbulls were used to take care of children</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/5-exercises-pet-to-lose-weight/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Captura-de-pantalla-2018-10-22-a-las-12.35.25-p.-m.-300x184.png"></a></div>


<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">5 exercises pet to lose weight</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/5-exercises-pet-to-lose-weight/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/what-are-the-right-toys-for-your-pet/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/356890-PAVKBG-677-300x300.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">What are the right toys for your pet?</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/what-are-the-right-toys-for-your-pet/">READ MORE</a></div></div>


<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/whats-the-right-dose-of-snacks-for-your-dog/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/camylla-battani-780956-unsplash.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">What’s the right dose of snacks for your dog?</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/whats-the-right-dose-of-snacks-for-your-dog/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/why-dogs-shouldnt-eat-chocolate/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/animal-animal-photography-cute-33102-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="grid-nav-bottom"><div class="pagination dark"><div class="paginate"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: No entiendo la consulta, la idea es que siempre el primer botón sea azul, el siguiente rojo, el siguiente verde y el posterior vuelva a ser azul?

Comment: Son esos 3 botones amigo, la idea es que siempre tengan esos colores como ha dicho y que todos los botones de las filas debajo tengan los mismos colores de cada uno ¿Si me explico?

Comment: Yo investigué un poco y encontré esto, pero lo aplico y se cambia en todos, no se que estoy haciendo mal: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.pt_BR.html

Comment: Deberías poner también el CSS que estás intentado aplicar para ver cual es el problema y porque no te funciona. A lo mejor no tienes los selectores adecuados o cin tu estructura HTML necesitas otra solución

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer agregando un id a cada enlace por ejemplo

```
   /*Codigo CSS*/

    #read1{
        background:;
    }

    #read2{
        background:;
    }

    #read3{
        background:;
    }

    #read4{
        background:;
    }

    #read5{
        background:;
    }
```

El HTML ya con id agregado

```
    <div id="post-grid-178" class="post-grid grid"> 
    <div class="grid-nav-top"></div> 
    <div class="grid-items " id=""> 
    <div class="item mix skin even flat blog "> 
    <div class="layer-media"> <a href="/../2018/10/23/a-canary-tells-its-owner-when-they-have-visitors/">
    <img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/sharon-mccutcheon-617866-unsplash-300x200.jpg"></a>

    </div> <div class="layer-content">
    <div class="element element_0 title">A canary tells its owner when they have visitors</div>
    <a target="_blank" id="read1"class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/a-canary-tells-its-owner-when-they-have-visitors/">READ MORE</a></div></div>
    <div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "> 
    <div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/get-to-know-the-dog-army-in-india/">
    <img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/animal-animal-photography-blur-89781-300x208.jpg"></a></div> 

    <div class="layer-content"> 
    <div class="element element_0 title">Get to know the dog army in India</div>
    <a id="read2"target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/get-to-know-the-dog-army-in-india/">READ MORE</a></div></div> 
    <div class="item mix skin even flat blog "> 
    <div class="layer-media">
    <a href="/../2018/10/23/the-5-fastest-races-in-the-world/">
    <img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Galgo_español-300x200.jpg"></a></div> 

    <div class="layer-content"> 
    <div class="element element_0 title">The 5 fastest races in the world</div>
    <a id="read3" target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/the-5-fastest-races-in-the-world/">READ MORE</a></div></div> 
    <div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "> 
    <div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/what-should-you-know-before-you-have-a-cat/">
    <img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/eric-han-540884-unsplash-300x200.jpg"></a></div> 
    <div class="layer-content"> 
    <div class="element element_0 title">What should you know before you have a cat?</div>
    <a id="read4" target="_blank"  class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/what-should-you-know-before-you-have-a-cat/">READ MORE</a></div></div> 
    <div class="item mix skin even flat blog ">

    <div class="layer-media">
    <a href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/adorable-animal-blur-825949-1.jpg"></a></div> 
    <div class="layer-content"> 
    <div class="element element_0 title">Why pitbulls were used to take care of children</div>
    <a id="read5"target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/">READ MORE</a></div></div> <div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/5-exercises-pet-to-lose-weight/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Captura-de-pantalla-2018-10-22-a-las-12.35.25-p.-m.-300x184.png"></a></div>
```

Ahora solo agregas el color a cada etiqueta background y sera diferente cada uno. Espero te sirva amigo

Comment: Si no es eso lo que necesitas dime y con gusto te ayudare.

Comment: Si estoy viendo la web ahorita y en vista movil tocaria modificar el width de las imagenes tambien porque usan como el 90% de la pantalla y se ven estiradas y si le pones el style directo en el html de cada etiqueta a es decir style=" background:red;"

Answer (score 0):

Si agregas es estilo en cada etiqueta de enlace te lo admite?

```
    <a target="_blank" style="background: black;"class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/">READ MORE</a>
```

[image: lo deje asi agregando el style en cada una directamente]

Comment: Si lo puedo hacer, pero por ejemplo en este caso me pondría negro todos los botones, ya lo aplico para que vea amigo

Comment: Si ya vi estan todos en negro

Comment: No puedes cambiar la clase todos tienen que ser iguales en class?

Comment: Si amigo porque si cambio la clase no me muestra los botones debido a que estos generan la clave con el ID del grid, ya le adjunto el código PHP

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85362/discussion-between-alberto-castellon-and-anto-j).

Answer (score 0):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo hecho con CSS (no modifiqué tu HTML) donde usa el fondo de los links en rojo para el primero, después azul, después verde, y después vuelve a comenzar:

```css
.grid-items .item a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.grid-items .item:nth-child(3n-1) a {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.grid-items .item:nth-child(3n) a {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="post-grid-178" class="post-grid grid">
<div class="grid-nav-top"></div>
<div class="grid-items " id="">
<div class="item mix skin even flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media">
<a href="/../2018/10/23/a-canary-tells-its-owner-when-they-have-visitors/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/sharon-mccutcheon-617866-unsplash-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">A canary tells its owner when they have visitors</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/a-canary-tells-its-owner-when-they-have-visitors/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/get-to-know-the-dog-army-in-india/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/animal-animal-photography-blur-89781-300x208.jpg"></a></div>


<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">Get to know the dog army in India</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/get-to-know-the-dog-army-in-india/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/the-5-fastest-races-in-the-world/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Galgo_español-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">The 5 fastest races in the world</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/the-5-fastest-races-in-the-world/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog ">
<div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/what-should-you-know-before-you-have-a-cat/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/eric-han-540884-unsplash-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">What should you know before you have a cat?</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/what-should-you-know-before-you-have-a-cat/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/adorable-animal-blur-825949-1.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">Why pitbulls were used to take care of children</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/why-pitbulls-were-used-to-take-care-of-children/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/5-exercises-pet-to-lose-weight/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Captura-de-pantalla-2018-10-22-a-las-12.35.25-p.-m.-300x184.png"></a></div>


<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">5 exercises pet to lose weight</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/5-exercises-pet-to-lose-weight/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/what-are-the-right-toys-for-your-pet/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/356890-PAVKBG-677-300x300.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">What are the right toys for your pet?</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/what-are-the-right-toys-for-your-pet/">READ MORE</a></div></div>


<div class="item mix skin odd flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/whats-the-right-dose-of-snacks-for-your-dog/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/camylla-battani-780956-unsplash.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="layer-content">
<div class="element element_0 title">What’s the right dose of snacks for your dog?</div><a target="_blank" class="element element_1 read_more" href="/../2018/10/23/whats-the-right-dose-of-snacks-for-your-dog/">READ MORE</a></div></div>

<div class="item mix skin even flat blog "><div class="layer-media"><a href="/../2018/10/23/why-dogs-shouldnt-eat-chocolate/"><img alt="" src="/../wp-content/uploads/2018/10/animal-animal-photography-cute-33102-300x200.jpg"></a></div>

<div class="grid-nav-bottom"><div class="pagination dark"><div class="paginate"></div></div></div>
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!